# Dynamic Menu with Sub menu in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have some JSON in the below format. I need to convert it into a menu with a sub menu when `sub-menu_location` is not equal to null, as below [image: Menu bar in image]

```html
{
  "data": [
    {
      "menu_name": "Primary Operations",
      "enabled": true,
      "sub-menu_location": null
    },
    {
      "menu_name": "Curated Games",
      "enabled": false,
      "sub-menu_location": null
    },
    {
      "menu_name": "Cricket",
      "enabled": false,
      "sub-menu_location": "outdoor"
    },
    {
      "menu_name": "football",
      "enabled": false,
      "sub-menu_location": "outdoor"
    },
    {
      "menu_name": "Hockey",
      "enabled": false,
      "sub-menu_location": "outdoor"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/kdcwjk img preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

- The example data you give in the question would only allow for a single sub-menu item.
- I do not know how you want to display this but from the picture I am guessing Bootstrap.
- I don't think Bootstrap supports dropdown sub-items by default so I am going to use the syntax in [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/ajaypatelaj/pen/prHjD)

### Potential solution

If you store the `data` object as a property in your component, the following template should give you something to start with:

```
<li>
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
    <li *ngFor="let menuItem of data" class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{menuItem.menu_name}}</a>
      <ul *ngIf="menuItem.sub-menu_location" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">{{menuItem.sub-menu_location}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```